# Not able to find a particular value in a column in pandas but I can find it in R

Tags: python, pandas

Df

```
 A
123
234
374
493
```

Python

```
Df[Df['A']==234]
```

I get no value.

R

```
Df[Df$A %in% c('234')]
```

The value is getting displayed.
What is the mistake that I do in pandas.
The number of rows are same in both python and R.

Comment: `'234'` is that a string? I dont know how R works but if so you are comparing as an integer in pandas `234`

Comment: Your R code dose not work as well ~

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> R : %in%
> Pandas : isin
> ```

```
Df[Df['A'].isin(['234'])]


#Df[Df$A%in% c('234'),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your R code, it looks like 234 is a string. Try:

```
Df[Df['A']=='234']
```

Answer (score 0):

234 is probably a string. Try to change it to a float in Python or try

```
Df[Df['A']=='234']
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the following code:

```
df.iloc[1]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but only work the case given in the question. OP wants to extract every location where `'234'` is present in the columns `'A'`.